# In ODI 12c not able to reverse engineer Hyperion table. Error : Could not connect on host <xyz.com> and port 11333

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator, data-integration

I am getting error while reverse engineer Hyperion Planning tables.

ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed.
Caused By: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 33, in 
........................................................
com.hyperion.odi.planning.ODIPlanningException: com.hyperion.odi.planning.ODIPlanningException: Could not connect the Planning instance on host [xyz.com], port [11333], check if connect information is correct.

Previously I was able to reverse engineer the tables. This is happened after we have applied the oracle patches on the server.

Could anyone help on this.?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to xyz.com port 11333 via telnet or via some SQL tool?  Were the Oracle patches for the Oracle RDBMS or Oracle Data Integrator?

Comment: @MarkStewart yes I tried connecting via telnet its working.  Patches are Weblogic CPU Patches.

Comment: Oh, forgot on telnet, did you include the port # in the telnet command?  That may identify a firewall issue, if a particular port is not open. For a typical Oracle database connection to port 1521 the command would be `telnet example.com 1521` and in your case, `telnet xyz.com 11333`

Comment: yes i tried that only it is working... Do i need to check something from the Hyperion side?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that part.